# modern ui apps don't show

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Since the last windows update, all the Windows modern UI apps don't show.

Here is a short story of the problem.

1. My windows boots to the classic desktop, let's assume it is empty, no apps running.
2. I press the windows button, the modern UI desktop appears, with this nice modern metro look full of colored rectangles.
3. I then click any of modern UI apps, but it just flashes and the screen reverts back to the classic desktop, empty, with the modern app icon on the taskbar.
4. I then click the icon on the taskbar, the app flashes and again the classic desktop appears empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you uninstall those updates does it work

Comment: I can't. I don't have access to Windows Updates, as the policy prevents it.

Comment: Sounds like you should seek support from those who can.

Comment: Since you have ran into a policy preventing removing the updates, is this is a work computer?  Have you discussed with your company's IT staff? (There are policies specifically for disallowing modern UI apps.)  What else have you tried already?  If you log into your computer as a different user, do they work for that user?

Comment: sorry, misleading description. I could login as administrator with full rights. But, I need to install the windows updates, because the rules of my client (I connect to their networks) oblige me to do it. Is there anything I can do to get my modern apps showing under the windows updates?

Comment: @PA. - Unless you are willing to test without the updates, to see if the functionality comes back, I am not sure how we can help. If it does work then you have to figure out which update causes the conflict.  It it doesn't work then you install the updates and you are exactly where you are today.  Without this critical troubleshooting ability I don't see how we can possible help you.

Comment: try all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx